# Smack - whether the message was sent?

Tags: java, networking, xmpp, smack

I use Smack 3.2.1
How to check, whether the message was sent, or there was some problem like network failure?
I do this:

```
connection.connect();
connection.addConnectionListener(this);
connection.login(auth.getUsername(), auth.getPassword());
// ... initializing e ...
Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(e.getAddress(), null);
try{
    /********at this moment network failures*******/
    chat.sendMessage(e.getMessage());
    log.info("Message was sent: " + e);
} catch (XMPPException ex){
    log.error("Error: " + e + ", ex=" + ex);
}
```

And every time it logs that message was sent, but in fact it wasn't.
There are also ConnectionListener methods, but they don't work, program just doesn't invoke them.

```
    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        log.info("connectionClosed()");
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception excptn) {
        log.info("connectionClosedOnError()");
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(int i) {
        log.info("reconnectingIn()");
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        log.info("reconnectionSuccessful");
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception excptn) {
        log.info("reconnectionFailed()");
    }
```

How to control network problems? I use Linux, if it matters.

UPD:
I realized that messages go to some queue, and when connection becomes fixed, messages are sent. I got an idea - check this queue before logging, but I don't know, how to get an access to it.